# Django forms Input type text keeps returning value "on" when clicking on the submit button

Tags: jquery, html, django, forms

I'm using Django forms for a registration with a checkbox at the end, but whenever I click on the submit button the value of the first input type gets changed to "on" . Note that the submit button is enabled only after the checkbox is checked .

I have used jQuery to try to output the value of that specific field and indeed it does not return the value I typed but only returns "on" . I Spent hours and hours on debugging but still can't find a way out .

form.html

```
<form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                   {% for field in form1 %}
                            {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
                            <span>{{ field.help_text|safe }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                   <div class="terms-con">
                        <ul>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="name"></li>
                            <li><a href="{%url 'main:terms_conditions'%}">I agree with the terms and conditions of the site</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <button type="submit" id="registerBtn" name="button" disabled="disabled">Register</button>
        </form>
```

forms.py

```
class AssociationForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Association
    fields = (
        'name',
    )
    labels = {
        'name': _("Association name")
    }
    widgets = {
        # 'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'value': ''}),
        # 'year_of_creation': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "Format: 'year-month-day'"})
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AssociationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
```

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

console.log($('input#id_name').val());

  $('#terms').click(function(){
    // check if the checkbox is checked
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $('#registerBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#registerBtn').attr('value', true);
    }else{
      $('#registerBtn').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Output of form

```
<form method="post">
                <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='jNEa0SK09m8PHCteaGT9ouPl2G5wdZapsboTwrARrwOAMeQjkufxceaakEEloW5K' />
<div id="div_id_name" class="form-group">

            <label for="id_name" class="control-label  requiredField">
                Association name<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
            </label>
 <div class="controls ">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="on" id="id_name" required class="textinput textInput form-control" maxlength="100" />

                </div>


    </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated .

## UPDATE

```
const idName = document.querySelector('input#id_name')
  idName.addEventListener('change', function(event){
    $('input#id_name').val($(this).val());
    console.log(event.target.value);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting `on` is the piece of Javascript code executed before user enters so you won't get the changed value. Try bind to the change event and get the user typed value.

```
const idName = document.querySelector('#id_name')
idName.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
})
```

Comment: thanks for the help but whenever I click on the submit button , the value being sent is "on" instead of the one that I typed .

Comment: whenever I fill in the form , it clearly returns the value in the console but when I click on submit it comes back to that "on" value

Comment: Yes. You haven't shown the actual submit code in your question right? So I can't guess the answer. May be you are doing it wrong. That should return the value when you really bind and listen.

Comment: No not that this code. I wanted to know the click function code. After you click which function will execute.

Comment: The more information you provide will help solve the problem fast. After user submitted what happens? Does that form handle by javascript of Jquery submit or Normal Form html form submit ?

Comment: It's just a normal html form submit . The form action is set to another page , so whenever I submit , if the form is valid it redirects me to another page .

Comment: That's unfortunate it's should return the correct value. Again I'm asking you to provide your full code. I can't guess where is the problem by just looking at the snippet of part.